# Notification bar only appears only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this dynamic piece of code. This should sends a request to PHP and get a response back. It should fadeIn() and fadeOut() every time there is a new notification. It shows the response as a notification bar at the top of the page, however, it only appears gradually once. When I send the request again, there would be a response but it will not show the notification bar again.
I'll be highly appreciated if someone could help me with this. Here is my code:

```
<script>
    function live_update(el) {
        var str = el.value ;
        var id  = el.id ;

        if (str.length==0) { 
        document.getElementById("live_update").innerHTML="";
        
        return;
      }

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
      {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("live_update").innerHTML=this.responseText;
          
            $("#live_update").addClass("bg-warning text-center text-dark p-2 h5 mx-auto");
            $('#live_update').fadeOut(3000);
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","profiles.php?act=live_update&u_key={u_key}&id="+id+"&q="+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help. Your code has worked perfectly :)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display the div *live_update* again, you need to use method fadeIn with the div *live_update* for its visibility. Also, you need to remove classes which you added when you display response first time. Otherwise, on every ajax response, it will keep adding to the div.

Try this.

```
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("live_update").innerHTML=this.responseText;
          
            $("#live_update").fadeIn("3000", function() {
            $(this).addClass("bg-warning text-center text-dark p-2 h5 mx-auto");
            });

            $("#live_update").fadeOut("3000", function() {
            $(this).removeClass("bg-warning text-center text-dark p-2 h5 mx-auto");
            });
         }
        }
```

You can use **fadeToggle** as well.

Comment: Please add some explanation of what you have done to solve the problem.